# Unity Child element only visible in play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay so I'm making UI app with dropdown menu which also has an option to search for item. So the problem is, that there's GameObject called Items, which has child components, but they only appear once I enter play mode and interact with dropdown menu. After I leave play mode I cannot see child objects anymore in hierarchy. I tried copying Items objects from play mode, and pasting it into hierarchy afterwards, but then search filter in dropdown menu stops working, it always only shows the first child no matter what keyword I search.

Comment: Please show your code! The child's and components are probably all instantiated on runtime via script or prefabs ..

Comment: thet's the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3k49NB

Comment: well as said ... checkout your `RebuildPanel()` method .. there you construct all instances of objects

Comment: Yes, I knew it's somewhere in that section, but I still don't know how to make gameobject to show these child objects, which i can see in play mode, or what to change. I'm very dumb in programming and I downloaded this script from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make in play mode to a scene and it's objects will not be saved, and for good reason. If you want those changes to stay, then you need to make those changes in edit mode. You can do this using editor scripts. You could also potentially put [ExecuteInEditMode] on your script to make it work in editor. If you need these things to happen in play mode, then you'll have to manually save all your changes to a save file and load them when playing again.